# Authentication type in DD paragraph confusion

Tags: java, authentication, basic-authentication, declarative-security

Could anyone please tell me why the following paragraph is incorrect:

> If your deployment descriptor
>   correctly declares an authentication
>   type of BASIC, the container
>   automatically requests a user name and
>   password whenever a user starts a new
>   session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because container would only request (as in "send an authentication challenge to browser") user name / password when user attempts to access a **protected** resource (as defined in descriptor); not when user session is created.

Details are in [JavaEE tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbo)